# Return list of elements until element greater than n

Tags: python, list

For example if I have a list `l = [0, 6, 2, 4, 8, 2, 4, 9]` and `n = 7`, the function should return:

```py
func(l, n) -> [0, 6, 2, 4]
```

Comment: check out `itertools.takewhile`.

Comment: What did you try? Please, spend some time reading ["How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and ["How do I ask a good question?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). You will get better results by following the tips in those articles.

Answer (score 1):

```
def filter(l, n):
  filtered = []
  for v in l:
    if v > n:
      return filtered
    filtered.append(v)
```